# Which is more expensive? hosting server for ASP.NET or for Java?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, java

I would like to know which one of them is more expensive?

Answer (score 2):

Not all Shared Hosting providers will support Java, while essentially every one will support either ASP.NET or PHP

Answer (score 1):

Cost of hosting / servers isn't usually determined by what application stack you put on top of it. A million other variables will have a more important effect on total cost. Similarly, cost of hosting isn't necessarily the best reason to choose one application stack over another.

There's an argument to made that deploying .NET on Windows incurs the Windows licensing cost whereas a Java EE server can be deployed on entirely open-source. That said, it's perfectly possible to run an ASP.NET server on linux under mono, just as it's easy to run a Java EE stack on top of operating systems costing a lot more than Windows.

Comment: With the recent Oracle/Sun acquisition, a lot of things are changing wrt "open-source" of Sun's technologies. OpenSolaris, for example, is no more. So it's not unreasonable to conclude that the cost of using the Java stack is likely to increase.

Comment: Whilst this is true, I'd point out that while both .NET and Java have open source implementations, it seems to me that the Java side follows the official releases much more closely than with .NET. My understanding is that implementations like OpenJDK, JBoss, Tomcat are kept fairly up to date with the Java releases from Oracle, whereas Mono is still a way behind giving full .NET 4 compatability.

Comment: From a technical standpoint, that's true. From a business standpoint, at this time, it's tough to say what Oracle will do to monetize their new acquisitions. With that, there's the potential for Java-based hosting to become less of a deal than it is/was. Like with OpenSolaris, you could use it for free to run your business. Now, SolarisExpress is $1000/yr. licensing. Oracle is already putting pressure/retrictions/limitations on OSS Java implementations.

Comment: then you would be mistaken.  Because of the all the preview releases and beta's for .Net 4, mono actually had their final stable version with .Net 4 support out _before_ microsoft's went RTM.

Comment: I was merely working off Mono's roadmap (http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap) where their listing for Mono 3.0 containing "Complete .NET 4.0 Core Support" has a release date of 'TBD'. While an existing release of Mono might have some .NET 4 compatibility, it appears to full short of full compatibility.